# App Engine cron jobs not running - Standard Environment - Java

Tags: google-app-engine

As the title says, I have a number of cron jobs set up on my Java web application hosted on AppEngine standard environment, but one or two of them fail to run.

Examining the logs, I can see that the httpRequest for the ones that fail have **302 error code**, indicating that the URL can't be found. The ones that work, return **200** as expected.

I can manually invoke the cron jobs' URLs and they work so it doesn't appear to really be a 302 problem. From the logs, Chrome sees a 200 response, but AppEngine sees 302:

[image: Chrome sees a 200 response, but AppEngine sees 302]

The cron.xml file is in the correct place and works for the other jobs. this is the cron entry that's failing:

```
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/home/cron/boatactivity/</url>
        <description>generate activities for boat movement</description>
        <schedule>every 3 hours from 00:00 to 21:00</schedule>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

And this is how it looks in the console:

[image]

I've checked an double checked the configuration and can't figure out what the problem is.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What's the result if you use the `Run Now` button in the cron status page?

Comment: BTW, 302 is a redirect, not a "URl can't be found" and may be expected depending on your app code and/or its configs. You need to provide more info, Try to determine what's that redirection using the Chrome Developer tools -> Network utility